# cannot understand sql injection explanations

Tags: php, mysql

Could somebody correct this statement to stop sql injection,
I have read through lots of answers but don't understand how to do it.

```
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, 
 $dbname);
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

 $sql = "UPDATE daydxx SET $T1 ='$Dsc', $T2 = '$SV'  WHERE date = '$Dt' AND 
 $T1 = '' OR date = '$Dt' AND $T1 IS NULL ";

 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {  etc etc
```

Comment: Use a framework that does all that and more like mysqli or PDO

Comment: Heh @juergend ... "*like mysqli or PDO*" ... I think you meant ...

Comment: worked it out restated the variable
 $Dsc = $_REQUEST['Dsc'];
 $Dc = str_replace("'", "\'", $Dsc);